# hide and show with jQuery not working on a button

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a button that when the user clicks it it is meant to show the first filed in my form. I have used jQuery toggle but when the button is clicked nothing seems to happen, what am I doing wrong?

```js
$("#chnagecar").click(function() {
  $("#car").toggle();
});
```

```css
#changecar{
  display:none:
}
```

```html
<p id ="news">Hello User<input type="button" id="changecar" value="Whst car do you have"></p>
<div id="car">
  <label required>Do you know what car you have? </label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="yes" value="yes" />Yes
  <input type="radio" id="no" value="no" />No
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Required isn't a valid attribute on `<label>`

Comment: Also, you have a typo in your id `$("#chnagecar").click(function() {` has to be `$("#changecar").click(function() {`

Comment: Your Jquery reads `$("#chnagecar").click(function()` notice the typo. It should be `#changecar`

Comment: have changed that but it still doesn't work and the console shows no errors :-(

Comment: use slideDown ... fadeIn ... show methods like $("#car").show()

Comment: OP is trying to toggle inline styles on CSS styles. That won't work

Comment: it worked before but I saved and closed my problem and when I came back it, it had stoped working. So confused

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code:

- `<label>` cannot have a `required` attribute.
- Your jQuery contains a typo `chnagecar > changecar`
- Your CSS display: none: has a : instead of a ; at the end.
- You're trying to toggle inline HTML style, instead of CSS.

Alright, so now that we

HTML:

```
<p id="news">Hello User<input id="changecar" type="button" value=
"What car do you have"></p>

<div id="car">
    <label>Do you know what car you have?</label><br>
    <br>
    <input id="yes" type="radio" value="yes">Yes <input id="no" type="radio"
    value="no">No<br>
    <br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#changecar").click(function() {
  $("#car").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

We're now having a `hidden` class that 'hides' an element with display: none; that gets toggled when the button is pressed.

Working codepen:
http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/bwkLvQ

Comment: need to do this in jQuery and I fixed my css but it still doesn't work

Comment: This.. is jQuery?

Comment: oh sorry so it is, been looking at that much code that it is all starting to look the same

Comment: sadly this still didn't fix it

Comment: Your comment is way too vague to actually describe what *doesn't work*  or *how it should work in the first place*

Comment: when the button is clicked in its meant to display the car div which is hidden. When the button is clicked nothing happens

Comment: @Rebekah why don't you update your post with the final html/css/script versions? this would be quite helpful to other users. (they keep posting answers based on your first version, pointing out the typo)

Comment: I way able to fix it, it ended up being something simple that i just couldn't see

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above comments, I would also suggest removing the `:` from the Display property. As stated in the [Firefox CSS Syntax Rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax#CSS_declarations_blocks), a semicolon is not required but is good practice.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Also, the current `:` actually disables the rule. Since it cannot get parsed properly

Comment: @Roberrrt, I realized that it would be better fit for a comment, but my reputation is not quite there to make one.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic root scaue is you have mis-spelled the div id name in 'changeCar' as 'chnageCar'.**

```
 $("#changecar").click(function () {
            $("#car").toggle();

        });`
```

Above will work.

Apart from that there are some improvement suggestions for the code;

- In CSS styles it should be semi colon at the end of changeCar ID not a colon.

`#changecar{ display:none;}`

- By setting display:none you are hiding the button and it is not visible to user. I think the style `#changecar{ display:none;}`is not required here and you can remove it.
- In the label "required" is not a valid attribute.

Here is the [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/buddhirameshi/3chcohe9/13/).

Comment: You're not posting anything new.

Comment: @Roberrrt You are suggesting to add a new CSS class named 'hidden' and .toggleClass('hidden'') and in my solution it is not required to add a new class and toggle() itself will work if the above suggestions are done.

Comment: Stuff that 'works' isn't always best practice. Seperating your logic from your style is something important you should always apply in your work, as much as possible.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/buddhirameshi/3chcohe9/13/
Here is the JSfiddle Link. 
Perhaps you will understand that there is no harm to the  separation of concerns in my suggestion.